# What is the quota limit of Gmail read in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I saw the present quota limit for Gmail read (attached the image below). So what does it mean ?

Does it mean 20,000 email threads OR 20,000 emails per day ?
Or it means the number of query we can make for Gmail service ?

**Update:** check this url https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard

Here the statement is bit different. It says "Gmail operation". 
Now I am bit confused.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 20k quota is referring to reads/writes using the [GmailApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app), excluding actual email sends.  These are mailbox manipulations like: getting inbox threads, marking a thread as important, labeling a thread, deleting spam threads, etc.

Most things that are listed under GmailApp are covered by this quota (except sendMail()). Sending email is covered by the 'Email recipients' quota.

Note that there is a more explicit [Quota documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) that has more information about Apps Script quotas and exception messages.